# Return already resolved promise

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have an existing project that has a lot of asynchronous functions that return promises.  I'm adding some caching so that in some cases the asynchronous functions will complete synchronously and would like to make this code shorter/better if possible:

```
        return $.Deferred(function(def) { def.resolve(); }).promise();
```

For example, I have a Data Service class that handles most AJAX requests that looks like this:

```
function DataService() {

    var self = this;

    self.makeRequest = function(functionName, data) {
        return $.Deferred(function(def) {

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService.asmx/" + functionName,
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var ex;
                    try {
                        ex = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        ex.message = ex.Message;
                        ex.Message = undefined;
                    } catch (ex2) {
                        ex = { message: "Invalid Response From Server:\r\n" + xhr.responseText };
                    }
                    if (ex.message == "LoginRequired") {
                        app.viewModels.main.loginRequired(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        app.showError(ex.message);
                    }
                    def.reject(ex.message);
                }
            });
        }).promise();
    }
}
```

Then I have a function in another class that currently always calls makeRequest:

```
self.deleteMe = function()
{
   return app.dataservice.makeRequest('deleteItem');
}
```

I want to update the deleteMe function so that it doesn't always call makeRequest, and instead just does some synchronous work and then returns.  It needs to return a promise though, because whatever called it will be expecting that, but it needs to be an "already completed/resolved promise".  Currently I am using the first set of code above to do that.  Seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

@Eselk,

In my experience, the `$.Deferred(function(def) {...});` construction is rarely needed, though I guess it can be quite useful in some circumstances.

Firstly, :

```
return $.Deferred(function(def) { def.resolve(); }).promise();
```

will simplify to :

```
return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
```

Secondly, in `DataService.makeRequest()` you can avoid the need for an explicit `$.Deferred` by exploiting `.then()`, as follows :

```
function DataService() {
    var self = this;
    self.makeRequest = function (functionName, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/" + functionName,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).then(null, function (xhr, status, error) {
            var ex;
            try {
                ex = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                ex.message = ex.Message;
                ex.Message = undefined;
            } catch (ex2) {
                ex = {
                    message: "Invalid Response From Server:\r\n" + xhr.responseText
                };
            }
            if (ex.message == "LoginRequired") {
                app.viewModels.main.loginRequired(true);
            } else {
                app.showError(ex.message);
            }

            return ex.message;
        });
    };
}
```

The key aspects here are :

- `$.ajax()` returns a promise-compatible jqXHR object, which (on success/error) is immediately acted upon and modified by `.then()`.
- `.then(null, ...)` - causes a new promise to be passed on, resolved with the same values as the original promise returned by `$.ajax()`. Thus, under the 'done' (ie ajax success) condition, `.then()` is completely transparent.
- `return ex.message;` - causes a new promise to be passed on, rejected with `ex.message`.

The nett effect should be identical to your original code though, IMHO, chaining `.then()` is significantly cleaner than setting everything up inside a `$.Deferred()` callback.

By the way, you may be able to avoid the need for `eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")")` etc by setting an appropriate HTTP header server-side such that your '.Message' appears directly as the `status` argument (or `xhr.status`?) of the fail callback. For example, in PHP you would do something like :

```
$message = "my custom message";
header("HTTP/1.1 421 $message");
exit(0);
```

I'm sure ASP offers the same capability.

IIRC, any 4xx series status code will do the job. 421 just happens to be one without a specific meaning.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I decided I need my ajax calls to be cancellable at higher levels, so I'm returning deferreds in most places now, so based on your answer I just need $.Deferred.resolve(); -- nice and clean.

Comment: I think you mean `$.Deferred().resolve().promise();`

Answer (score 30):

Simply use `return $.when();` to return *an already resolved promise*.

> If you don't pass it any arguments at all, jQuery.when() will return a
>   resolved promise.

**Reference:** https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

---

**Notes:**

- This is the same as `return $.when(undefined);` which leads to the following rather cool trick which avoids any use of arrays and `apply`.

If you want to wait for a variable number of promises to complete *in parallel* then you can use this pattern in a loop:

```
var promise;   // Undefined is treated as an initial resolved promise by $.when
while (insomeloop){
    promise = $.when(promise, newpromise);
}
```

then make a final call on completion with:

```
promise.then(function(){
    // All done!
});
```

e.g.

```
var promise;$.when
var $elements = $('.some-elements');
$elements.each(function(){
     var $element = $(this).fadeout();
     promise = $.when(promise, $element.promise());
});
promise.then(function(){
    // All promises completed!
});
```

**The downsides are minor:**

- each call to `when` wraps the previous promise in a new promise. A minor overhead and you no longer need to maintain and evaluate an array of promises.
- no values can be directly passed through to the final function. As you typically do not want the return values from *parallel promises*, this is minor.
- failure of a single promise will abort the final wait early, so you need to ensure all promises will be fulfilled.

Comment: Without argument will not resolve, however even `undefined` as argument will resolve. Strange.