# Idiom for a pre-made already resolved ES6 promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a `.then()` waterfall with promise steps, and sometimes a promise doesn't apply.  So I have code like this:

```
var maybe_noop_promise;
if (some_condition)
    maybe_noop_promise = fetch(...).then(...)... // work need be done
else
    maybe_noop_promise = /* code for resolved promise (?) */
```

Were I using jQuery, there's a suggestion that this [can be done with `$.when()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33656679/211160).  And it appears [`Promise.all([])` is resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49849679/211160), which I guess is fine, though I don't know if that is wasteful or slow.

Is there a favored idiom for a pre-cooked resolved promise?

Comment: `Promise.resolve(value)`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks.  Though this is an example of what I would call a "good duplicate" in that I would never have found the other question with the search terms I was using.  Sidenote that `Promise.resolve()` appears to work with no value passed.

Comment: Yes, `value` is just taken as `undefined` if you pass no arguments.